# Regex to match 32-character mixed-char string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need the Javascript regex to match strings like this...

> loYm9vYzE6Z-aaj5lL_Og539wFer0KfD
>
> pxeGxvYzE6o97T7OD2mu_qowJdqR7NRc
>
> gwaXhuYzE6l3r1wh5ZdSkJvtK6uSw11d

They are 32-character strings with mixed alpha, numeric, punctuation and case.

I had been using `/[\w-]{32}/g` (actually, `var matches = inputData.body.match(/[\w-]{32}/g)`) - but I just noticed that it is incorrectly plucking matching strings out of a string with longer than 32 characters.

That is, it found, in

> "aHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAuZTJtYS5uZXQvYXBwMi9hdWRpZW5jZS9vcHRfb3V0LzE0‌​MDEwMTQvMTQwMDgxNC81‌​NjQ2MzE4Lw==",
>   the two strings "aHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAuZTJtYS5uZXQvYXBw" and
>   "Mi9hdWRpZW5jZS9vcHRfb3V0LzE0MDEw".

That's not the right behaviour - I don't want to match a 32-character string that is simply part of a longer string, however unlikely that may be. Do I need to use a word boundary or something?

Would that then be something like `/b/[\w-]{32}/g/b`? I'm unclear of the construction.

Comment: Yep, word boundaries (`\b`) should solve this problem for you. Only problems are that you're using `/` instead of ```\``` and your second use of `\b` is placed to the right of the `g` global modifier, which is actually outside of the regex pattern.

Comment: So do I want `\b/[\w-]{32}\b/g`? Should I double-slash either of the \bs?

Comment: Almost. The forward slashes denote the beginning and the end of regex patterns in many languages, much like quotes around strings. What you're looking for is `/\b[\w-]{32}\b/g`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the format and delimiters in your file, you could do this a number of ways:

```
`\b[\w-]{32}\b`
```

would force word boundaries around the values

```
`\s[\w-]{32}\s`
```

would force white space around the values

```
`^[\w-]{32}$`
```

would only match a line with a 32 character value

```
`(?!([\w-=]{33})[\w-]{32}`
```

will match any 32 character string, unless there's a 33 character string, the equal specifically will exclude the last available match from an alpha num string containing a follow on excluded character.  However, for this to work against any longer string, other than the example provided, it needs to be combined with one of the first 2 examples I gave.